# Connect to a 2030.5 client that requires a specifice cipher suite using Dart SecureSocket

Tags: dart, tls1.2

2030.5 client requires cipher - `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8`.

I tried using SecureSocket but Ciphersuite doesn't include this and it results in `SSLV_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE`.

```
 Future<void> connecToMeterAgent(String host) async {
     SecureSocket secureSocket;
     var context = SecurityContext();
     try {
    
      final certificate = CertificateUtility().generateSelfSignedCertificate();
      final List<int> certificateBytes = utf8.encode(certificate);
      context.setTrustedCertificatesBytes(certificateBytes);   
      secureSocket = await SecureSocket.connect(
        host,
        METER_AGENT_PORT,
        context: context,
        onBadCertificate: (X509Certificate c) {
          XeDebugPrint.error(
              msg: 'Certificate WARNING: ${c.issuer}:${c.subject}');
          return true;
        },
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 60),
      );
      secureSocket.writeln('GET / HTTP/1.1');
      secureSocket.writeln('Host: $host:$METER_AGENT_PORT/dcap');
      secureSocket.writeln('');
      await secureSocket.flush();
      await for (var line in secureSocket
          .transform(utf8.decoder as StreamTransformer<Uint8List, dynamic>)) {
        XeDebugPrint.info(msg: line);
      }
      secureSocket.close();
    } on SocketException catch (se) {
      XeDebugPrint.error(msg: 'socket exception: $se.toString()');
      rethrow;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      XeDebugPrint.error(msg: 'unhandled exception: $e.toString()');
      rethrow;
    }
   }
```

Wireshark packet tracer also gave the same error.

Is there a way to provide a specific cipher?